# Запуск браузера в безголовом режиме

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

Вот такой код нашел:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options 
opts = Options() 
opts.set_headless() 
assert opts.headless # без графического интерфейса. 
browser = Firefox(options=opts) 
browser.get('https//.....')
```

Но валится вот с таким логом:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "C:/Users/venv/Proba_headless.py", line 5, in <module>
    opts.set_headless() AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'set_headless'
```

Answer (score 2):

Это старая версия, она помечена как `Deprecated`, теперь так:

```
opts.headless = True
```

Comment: поменял. Вот такая ошибка:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

Comment: Видимо надо так  импортировать и использовать `from selenium import webdriver`, `webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)`

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Comment: Вот и падает с логом из первого коммента(

Comment: хм, попробуйте драйвер переустановить

Comment: И это пробовал. Просто валится

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте передавать опцию `--headless`.

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1e577b466e51280e6edaaf0da32767564828cc7e/selenium__examples/hide_window__invisible__headless.py):

```
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/doodles')

print('Title: "{}"'.format(driver.title))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: скопипастил Ваш код. Та же ошибка(

Comment: @СергейБогданов, аргумент что-ли изменили... давно селениум не пользовался, попробуйте `firefox_options` вместо options, хотя по тому конструктору выходит что и options поддерживается. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/7fdf318b4094af637cb17d0f39ad0755b8f5cd83/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#L43

Comment: @СергейБогданов, фигня какая-то... Попробуйте перейти в описание типа Firefox (Ctrl + левой кнопкой тыкнуть) и посмотрите что у него в `__init__` передается. Там должен быть `options=None`

Comment: `options=None` это значение по умолчанию, `firefox_options` помечен как `Deprecated`